# How can I parse a string input to match a field in a json?

Tags: json, node.js, string, parsing, field

*i know the question is very unclear and ambiguous, so i'll elaborate:*

**i want to parse a string input from a user, and make it a valid field name that i can access as part of a json.**

---

### example:

assuming we have this json:

```
var user = 
{
   id: 1,
   email: 'some@email.com',
   name:
   {
      first: 'stack',
      last: 'overflow'
   }
};
```

let's say the user input this:

`enter a valid field: "name.first"`

i want the app to return this:

`return user.name.first;`

or interchangeably:

`return user['name']['first'];`

**how can i do it without loops and ugly code?**

i'm asking because i saw it in couple of open source plugins, like [mongoose-deep-populate](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate), and there you can input the way i want my users to do.

*btw, i'm terrible at explaining myself in english, so please critic me if you don't understand and i'll try to rephrase.*

Thanks in advance!

Amit

Comment: Quick search for `javascript string to dot notation` will give you many results. There are multiple ways of doing this but some people say it's actually bad to do it. (Bad application design if you need to use it) also is bad performance wise

Comment: @Molda I actually figured that it'll be bad for performance. Gonna think of a better way. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var your_string = user_input;
return eval ("user." + your_string);
```

I've tried it with a json file and it worked.